# How to get a function pointer to the overloaded function that the compiler chooses?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I get a function pointer to the overloaded function that the compiler would choose after inspecting the arguments? In this example:

```
#include <iostream>

void MyFunction(float a){}
void MyFunction(int a){}

int main()
{
  float a;

  MyFunction(a);

  void (*manualFunctionPointer)(float);
  manualFunctionPointer(a);

  // automaticFunctionPointer = ?
}
```

I have specified that I want a function pointer to the function that accepts a float and returns void. The compiler can certainly figure that out by itself, because the MyFunction(a) call calls the right function. Is there a way to get a function pointer to the function that the compiler chooses?

Comment: I think you have to use a template function somewhere... I don't see it possible otherwise

Comment: Have you tried `manualFunctionPointer = MyFunction`?

Comment: The problem is I have to call the function like this QtConcurrent::run(FunctionPointer, argument1, argument2, ...). So apparently it has trouble deducing the overloaded function it should use at that point. I wanted to deduce it before the call and then pass the deduced function pointer to QtConcurrent::run.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - I don't have member functions anywhere here, right?

Comment: @DavidDoria: Oops -- I glanced at `QtConcurrent::run` and thought "member function", and didn't pay attention to the fact that you wanted to call a member function, but pass it a pointer to a normal function. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: AFAIK, I've tried to solve this before and came away concluding that it's not possible.

Comment: @GMan: That's what I have concluded too, unfortunately. If you had direct access to the overload set, this could be done relatively easily, but with current C++? Sorry, I don't see a way. Maybe possible when we get introspection, but until then, meh.

Comment: I once wrote a utility class you could use like `overload_set<void(int), void(long), void(char), void(int*)>()('a')` and which would output `[void(char), void(int), void(long)][void(int*)]`. That is, first list the accepting functions in order of priority, and then the non-accepted functions (that could either not accept the argument by themselfs, or were ambiguous with the other overloads still in the set).

Comment: @sehe it's on my ext4 disk that I cannot read without crashing my windows 7 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the float in

```
void (*manualFunctionPointer)(float);
```

With

```
void (*manualFunctionPointer)(decltype(a));
```

Then whatever a changes too, manualFunctionPointer will follow

Comment: This isn't quite the same. Consider if `a` were `char`. The normal call would still work, because the compiler implicitly converts `char` to `int`, but this solution will fail because there is no overload with that exact signature.

Comment: @John Bandela - great, I think this is what I was looking for. However, when I do that (actually, either the manual or decltype version of the above), I get "manualFunctionPointer used uninitialized" warning?

Comment: @DavidDoria: Well in your question, you never initialized it, you just used it.

Comment: @GManNickG - I see what you're saying, but in my case the types do match exactly. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @GManNickG - what am I supposed to initialize it to?

Comment: @DavidDoria: It's a function pointer, so it needs to point to a function. You can assign it the value of any compatible function, like `manualFunctionPointer = MyFunction`. Here the compile will pick the only matching overload.

Comment: @GManNickG Is there some magic to get it to match to a const parameter? I tried this: http://ideone.com/9nZ2OL  - it's close (it matches to a version (commented) that takes a non-const parameter), but I can't get it to match to the const version.

Comment: As this was a fairly separate question, I've moved it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636949/cant-convert-a-function-with-a-const-parameter-to-a-function-pointer

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

void MyFunction(float a){std::cout << "float\n";}
void MyFunction(int a){std::cout << "int\n";}

template<typename Func, typename T>
void Do( Func f, T t )
{
    f(t);
}
template<typename T>
void DoMyFunction( T t )
{
  Do(static_cast<void(*)(T)>(MyFunction), t);
}
template<typename T>
void DoSomeFunction( T t, void(*func)(T) )
{
  Do(func, t);
}
int main()
{
  float a;

  MyFunction(a);

  void (*manualFunctionPointer)(float) = MyFunction;
  manualFunctionPointer(a);

//  Do(MyFunction, a); -- does not compile
  Do(static_cast<void(*)(float)>(MyFunction), a);
  DoMyFunction(a);
  DoSomeFunction(a, MyFunction);
}
```

The above works.  I picked a MyFunction in 4 different ways.

If you are willing to do some boilerlate, and want to solve the "what if a is a `char`" problem, then this might help:

```
// wrap the idea of calling MyFunction in a type:
struct MyFunctionFunctor {
  template<typename T> static auto Do( T&& t )->decltype(MyFunction(std::forward(t))) {
    return MyFunction(std::forward(t));
  }
};
// Calling MyFunctionFunctor::Do( x ) will basically do static dispatch on all of
// the overloads of MyFunction

// wrap the idea of dispatching a variable to a functor:
template<typename T, typename Functor>
struct Dispatch {
  static auto Do( T t )->decltype( Functor::Do( t ) )
  {
    return Functor::Do( t );
  }
}

int main()
{
  char a;
  auto func_ptr = &Dispatch<decltype(a), MyFunctionFunctor>::Do;
  func_ptr(a);
}
```

but, as noted, this requires we wrap our `MyFunction` up so that it is described by a type.  I'm not aware of a way to do this without boilerplate.

Comment: there I still have to know "float" is the type of 'a' though. John Bandela's void (*manualFunctionPointer)(decltype(a)); is what I was looking for :)

Comment: If you want that, you might have to iterate over every type a can be implicitly promoted to.  For non user defined conversions this is theoretically possible, then use an insane SFINAE on the list of types to find the first one that works with your function pointer.  It probably is not worth it.  I cannot figure out how to do this with user defined conversions without lots of help from the cost of the conversion.  If we had constexpr function pointers I could do this with a template class static method wrapper.  Or if the func was a functor which I could call by type.

Comment: @GManNickG I think I added some code for a variation that works with `char a`.  I did not compile that code, so there could be typos.

Comment: @Yakk: In fact, your boiler-plate code is close to how I think overloading should have been implemented in the language. :)

Comment: @GManNockG If we only had compile-time function references as legal template types (naturally you wouldn't be allowed to take their address).  Then I could generate that boilerplate.  Damn you imperfect language (or, maybe, imperfect language skills on my part...)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: This is not really a solution; it's more of a cheat. But I think it does what is needed.

```
#define INVOKE(hof, func, arg) \
   hof([](const decltype(arg)& arg_){return func(arg_);}, arg)
```

Example:

```
// This function mimics the signature of QtCollector::run for testing
template <typename Functor, typename Arg1>
auto QtConcurrent_run(Functor functor, const Arg1 &arg1)
      -> decltype(functor(arg1))
{
      return functor(arg1);
}

#include <iostream>

int f(int x) { std::cout << "int" << " " << x << std::endl; return x; }
double f(double x) { std::cout << "double" << " " << x << std::endl; return x; }

int main() {
  INVOKE(QtConcurrent_run, f, 3);
  INVOKE(QtConcurrent_run, f, 3.14);
  INVOKE(QtConcurrent_run, f, '3');
  return 0;
}
```

See it [here](http://ideone.com/CTSPJW) on ideone.

The original answer follows, for historical purposes and a bit of explanation.

---

Just for clarity, because this is an interesting question but perhaps it is more important for you to get your project moving, is there a reason why you don't want to just wrap the various function overrides into a functor struct, and pass the functor struct directly to QtConcurrent::run, which will happily accept such a thing?

If all the definitions of the function were in a single class, then there would be no problem:

```
struct f_collector {
  ReturnType1 f(ArgType1 arg);
  ReturnType2 f(ArgType2 arg);
  ReturnType3 f(ArgType3 arg);
  // ...
  // Make it a functor:
  template<typename Argtype>
  auto operator()(const Argtype& arg) -> decltype(f(arg)) { return f(arg); }
}
```

Then you could call `QtConcurrent::run(f_collector(), argument)` and it would Just Work (unless you need perfect forwarding, but that's a minor detail).

So I had the following idea, which was to build a functor like the above on the fly, which basically means feeding it a lambda expression. The lambda itself is easy enough boilerplate; easy enough to make a macro out of it:

```
// This is the functor
template<typename Arg, typename Func> struct wrapper {
  wrapper(Func f) : f(f) {}
  const Func f;
  auto operator()(Arg arg) const -> decltype(f(arg)) {return f(arg);}
};

// As usual, a make_* function, because you can't template deduce a constructor
template<typename Arg, typename Func>
wrapper<Arg, Func> make_wrapper(Func f) {
  return wrapper<Arg, Func>(f);
}

// Boilerplate inside a macro
#define INVOKE(hof,func,arg) \
   hof(make_wrapper<decltype(arg)>( [](const decltype(arg)& arg_) { \
                                      return func(arg_); \
                                    }), \
       arg) 

// The above was ugly, but it's easy to use. For testing, I define
// this with a similar signature to QtConcurrent::run
template <typename Functor, typename Arg1>
auto QtConcurrent_run(Functor functor, const Arg1 &arg1)
      -> decltype(functor(arg1))
{
      return functor(arg1);
}

#include <iostream>

int f(int x) { std::cout << "int" << " " << x << std::endl; return x; }
double f(double x) { std::cout << "double" << " " << x << std::endl; return x; }


int main() {
  INVOKE(QtConcurrent_run, f, 3);
  INVOKE(QtConcurrent_run, f, 3.14);
  INVOKE(QtConcurrent_run, f, '3');
  return 0;
}
```

But then I remembered that lambda's, along with their other virtues, can be automatically converted to function pointers as long as they have no captures. And this lambda has no captures, because the only external symbol is the function itself, and that is not an object with automatic storage class. So, I think the bottom line is, you can actually do this with a bit of boilerplate:

```
#define INVOKE(hof, func, arg) \
   hof([](const decltype(arg)& arg_){return func(arg_);}, arg);
```

Comment: I don't follow what you mean?

Comment: I added some really ugly but working code. (Warning: uses macros and lambdas. Together.)

Comment: @DavidDoria: It works with your other example, too. See it live here: http://ideone.com/ADxfz6

Comment: Thanks. That is quite involved :) I think I'll see how far I can get with simply using the decltype()'s to get the overloaded function pointer. If that starts to fail, I'll revisit your macro.

Comment: @DavidDoria, yeah, it was quite involved. I managed to simplify it almost to the point where I'd claim it was a solution to your original problem. (At least, now there is only one little macro; no more wrappers.)