# Can't convert a function with a const parameter to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

Even by explicitly mentioning that the parameter in the function pointer is const, it doesn't seem to be able to convert the function to this type:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Image{};

template <typename TPixel>
static void
FillImage(const Image<TPixel>* const image){}
//FillImage(Image<TPixel>* const image){} // Replacing the above line with this one compiles fine

int main()
{
  typedef Image<float> ImageType;
  ImageType* image = new ImageType;
  void (*autoFunctionPointer)(const decltype(image)) = FillImage;
  autoFunctionPointer(image);
}
```

Can anyone explain how to make it do that conversion?

Comment: You're missing a `const`, currently the parameters expand to `ImageType* const`. You can't easily get that through `decltype`.

Comment: If you're using C++11 anyway, why not just `auto`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout - I have to specify the overload that I want to use (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632507/how-to-get-a-function-pointer-to-the-overloaded-function-that-the-compiler-choos for more details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` applies to the pointer.

So, `const decltype(image)` is equivalent to `ImageType* const` and *not* `const ImageType*`

If you change `image` to

```
const ImageType* image = new ImageType;
```

the first version of `FillImage()` works as expected.

To get a `const ImageType*` you can use [std::remove_pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_pointer/)

```
#include <type_traits>
...
void (*autoFunctionPointer)(const std::remove_pointer<decltype(image)>::type *) = FillImage;
```

Comment: so how would I get 'const ImageType*' then?

Comment: @DavidDoria: Try `const decltype(*image)* const`.

Comment: @GManNickG This doesn't work, because `decltype(*image)` is of type `ImageType&` and you cannot define `ImageType& const`.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work. @OlafDietsche Any suggestions of things that might :) ?

Comment: @DavidDoria Besides the change to image, unfortunately not. *If* I find something, I will update my answer, but don't hold your breath. ;-)

Comment: @DavidDoria It's easier than I thought, look at my updated answer.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: Oops. Then this should work: `const std::remove_reference<decltype(*image)>::type* const`.

Comment: @GManNickG Yes, I just tried your version and it compiles without problem.

Answer (score 0):

`FillImage` is a template, not a function. Try some variant of `FillImage<float>`.